# Monitor Network Traffic for a Specific Computer Program

Tags: networking

I am looking for a way to monitor network traffic for a specific program running on my computer. The program is running as a service on Windows 10 Pro x64, and I am interested in seeing the data packets that it is sending and receiving. How could I go about doing this? I have heard of utilities such as WireShark, but I do not know if it is capable of doing what I am trying to do.

Comment: Wireshark will show you all traffic exiting your network interface, but it cannot filter on ProcessId, so you have to figure out which ports those processes are using and filter to show them exclusively. Per this thread over on SO, the Microsoft Network Monitor, or Network Analyzer may be a better bet for tracing a specific processes connections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339691/filter-by-process-pid-in-wireshark#1339717

Comment: @FrankThomas I am trying the Microsoft Network Monitor now, but for some reason, the "Network Conversations" list does not show the service in it.

Comment: Are you running the tool as Administrator? It is quite possible that MS filters the data out before we can see it, just to hide the telemetry.

Comment: @FrankThomas I hadn't thought to try that, but I certainly will.

Comment: have you tried a conversation filter like `Conversation.ProcessName == "System"`? Unfortunately many services use rundll32 instead of a discrete executable, and it looks like you can't filter on PID. you may still have to find ways to filter out some of the noise.

Answer (score 0):

WireShark is exact tool you need. You can filter and see those packages and even recompile whole data from packets. - [WireShark official guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/) 
Try using resource monitor. You can open it from task manager>File>New Task> resmon for just how many bytes it sending.

Comment: How can I use WireShark for a specific program though? Surely there is a way to filter the information out in some way, even if it is not by process ID.

Comment: The best approach in Wireshark then is to filter by port, but that means you have to identify all the ports a process uses in advance, which can be difficult if it establishes many connections that exist for only a limited period of time. Perhaps the best bet is to use Sysinternals TCP view filtered by application, so that you can identify when new ports are involved in a connection.